# Bash and/or Zsh: Is it possible to customize the Vi insert mode to create a bind that moves a specific number of characters?

Tags: bash, zsh, line-editor

I have a Vim configuration that is somewhat unconventional. I bind Shift+H and Shift+L to move left by 7 characters and move right by 7 characters, respectively. This makes it easier for my brain to time the keyboard repeat to rapidly position the cursor where I want it to go as quickly as practically possible.

Anyway, I'm curious whether mapping a single key to such an action (move seven characters) like this is even possible, and I'd likely need to patch the shell itself. But, maybe the key binding system could allow for it?

I don't believe doing conversion or mapping at any other level (such as the terminal emulator) makes sense, as I need the terminal itself to keep sending the usual `H` and `L` characters.

Comment: For bash, the readline documentation ([here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-vi-Mode) and [here](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html#Documentation)) is frustratingly bare about its implementation of vi commands. But I don't believe they have implemented maps, so you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

`CURSOR` according to the `zshzle(1)` docs indicates that that can be moved about in ZSH:

```
rm ~/.zcompdump
bindkey -v
autoload -U compinit
compinit
function leftsevent {
    CURSOR=$(( CURSOR - 7 ))
}
function rightsaidfred {
    CURSOR=$(( CURSOR + 7 ))
}
zle -N leftsevent
zle -N rightsaidfred
bindkey H leftsevent
bindkey L rightsaidfred
```

(There does not appear to be any need on a single line of input to use bounds checking for `< 0` or `> $#BUFFER` but that might be a good thing to do...)

Comment: this is amaaaziiing

Comment: Is there an important reason why you remove `~/.zcompdump`? Hm, it does seem like there is a lot I don't understand yet about compinit, etc.

Comment: That line may help when you're fiddling around with new completions, and is not-so-much for day-to-day operations.

Comment: @StevenLu Zle is superior to bash's use of readline in many ways, but here you can do something similar with `bind -x` and `READLINE_POINT`. Searching for `READLINE_POINT` on this site should turn up some examples.